# Openscenegraph to Unreal Engine

Tags: blender, 3dsmax, openscenegraph

Is there a way to export an openscenegraph scene to unreal engine? So for instance perhaps export to a format supported by 3ds max or blender would be first step, if so , then how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

As user Kaveh Rassoulzadegan says FBX is the native import format for Unreal and OpenSceneGraph *can* be compiled with support for both import and export of FBX files.

Another path can be to use **osgconv** export to *Alias Wavefront OBJ* format. Support for this format is built-in in OpenSceneGraph and do not require any external code:

```
osgconv infile.osgb outfile.obj
```

Then import the generated outfile into 3D studio Max and export to FBX.

The quality of the exported files *may* differ between which format you select on and it can be wise to evalute which format suits your initial model best.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, OpenSceneGraph appear to already propose a fair amount of file interchange plug-ins. Not sure how well they output osg scenes, but it would perhaps be worth testing them.

Have you inspected those extensions ?

As for exporting geometries toward Unreal Engine, I would recommend using a FBX exportation plugin.
This should let you either export geometries directly to Unreal as well as most DCC tools such as 3DSMax or Maya.

https://github.com/openscenegraph/OpenSceneGraph/tree/master/src/osgPlugins